# Isolating a website DIV for an Android webview

Tags: java, php, android, xml, html

I'm a fairly poor programmer so forgive me if I don't explain this as well as I could.

I'm looking to view this webpage on my android device in an app I'm making:

http://heroes-ofnewerth.blogspot.com/

But if you inspect the elements of the site, I would like to only view what's under:

`div-blog-posts`

So the question is I'm asking is, by what method would I be able to only view the blog posts of that blog site in an Android webview.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to ask the author of this blog to give access to his rss feed. Then you would just have to parse it and would only have the blog posts.

The hard way, is to download the entire page, load it in a xml parser then extract the div-blog-posts and make it the root of a new xml element.

For xml parsing, see : http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html

For RSS feed parsing, see : http://code.google.com/p/android-rss/

Answer (score 0):

http://feeds.feedburner.com/blogspot/JHdXe

I don't know if this helps, but here's an RSS feed of hte blog, is that what you meant?